# MiGLayout sizing not working properly in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, miglayout

Here's my snippet:

```
package javafxdemo;

import org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.MigPane;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXDemo extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start (Stage stage) throws Exception {
                MigPane root = new MigPane();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);

                Button b = new Button("Hello");
                root.getChildren().add(b);

                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setTitle("FX");
                stage.show();
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
                launch (args);
        }
}
```

When running the gui doesn't show properly: the frame size is smaller than the button. Why does it happens? In HBox Layout when setting the scene it is automatically resized, so why with MiGLayout it doesn't work?

I'm using MigLayout 4.3

Comment: I had similar problems with MigPane myself.  It seems MigPane breaks some common conventions.  I had to switch to using GridPane.  The good news is GridPane is much easier to use than GridBag and is actually not too far off from MigPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I filed an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/miglayout/issues/detail?id=8) and later found out a workaround for this:
just add `stage.sizeToScene()` after `stage.show()`.