# Adapt Stage size to its children in JavaFx2 and MigLayout 4.2

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml, miglayout

I have an app where we manage multiple screens. In order to do that we have the next code (I will add only the important methods).

**ScreenManager.java**

```
public class ScreenManager extends StackPane {

    private final HashMap<String, Node> screens = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean showScreen(final String idScreen) {
         if (this.screens.get(idScreen) != null) {
             if (!this.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                 // Hide actual screen and show new one
                 this.getChildren().remove(0);
                 this.getChildren().add(0, this.screens.get(idScreen));
             } else {
                 // Show first screen
                 this.getChildren().add(this.screens.get(idScreen));
             }
             return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
}
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
     // Initialize screenManager
     ScreenManager screenManager = ScreenManager.getInstance();

     // Here I load my screens into screenManager

     final Scene screen = new Scene(screenManager);
     stage.setResizable(false);
     stage.setScene(screen);
     stage.show();

     // Show first screen
     screenManager.showScreen(IConstants.LOGIN_PAGE);
}
```

**login.fxml**

```
<MigPane id="rootPane" fx:controller="domain.myControllers.LoginController"
    styleClass="main-panel"
    layout="insets 25"
    cols="[label, pref!][grow, ::300]"
    rows=""
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

<Label text="Name" styleClass="label12" /> <TextField fx:id="name" MigPane.cc="growx, wrap" />
<Label text="Password" styleClass="label12" /> <PasswordField fx:id="password" MigPane.cc="growx, wrap" />

<Button text="Enter" onAction="#login" MigPane.cc="skip, gap :push, gaptop 15, wrap"  />

<Label fx:id="messageLabel" styleClass="result-message" MigPane.cc="span, growx, gaptop 15, wrap" />
```

The app works fine, but when I show the first screen the size of the stage is a lot bigger than it should be, and everytime I change the screen, it doesn't change at all, it keeps the first size.

Some ideas about how can I make it to adapt to the actual screen?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I found out that showing/adding the screen before define the Screen, the Stage tries to actually resize to its content.

```
     // Show first screen
     screenManager.showScreen(IConstants.LOGIN_PAGE);

     final Scene screen = new Scene(screenManager);
     stage.setResizable(false);
     stage.setScene(screen);
     stage.show();
```

But there is still a problem with my **login.fxml** or with **MigLayout** because it shows a tiny screen (1*2cm more or less).

I tried adding the next layout and it worked:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
```

So the question is, why doesn't it work with MigLayout? Why doesn't it define a pref width/height with my code?

**EDIT2**

Adding jewelsea's solution my app renders the first screen (using MigPane) with its correct size, however, the rest of screens keep this initial size so if they are bigger they don't fit. I don't know if it's MigPane's fault or StackPane, but in this situation where they don't fit, JavaFX tries to render them smaller, so the labels appear with 3 dots (...) and the textfields a lot smaller.

```
     // Show first screen
     screenManager.showScreen(IConstants.LOGIN_PAGE);

     final Scene screen = new Scene(screenManager);
     stage.setResizable(false);
     stage.setScene(screen);
     stage.show();
     stage.sizeToScene();
```

So it seems that everytime I remove or add a child to my StackPane, it doesn't force a resizing. Ideas?

**EDIT3**

Apparently there is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/miglayout/issues/detail?id=8) with MigLayout 4.2 and JavaFX that affects the resizing process. That's why we have to use *stage.sizeToScene()*. It's been release MigLayout 5.0 that sholves the problem, but it's not available for JavaFx2, only JavaFx8. So at least that someone knows other workaround, we are stack.

I also tried calling *stage.sizeToScene()* after every *getChildren.add*, but the stage is not resized properly, showing a tiny screen.

There is another post in Stackoverflow talking about the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386589/miglayout-sizing-not-working-properly-in-javafx) where the poster explains the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

[`stage.sizeToScene()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--)

> Set the width and height of this Window to match the size of the content of this Window's Scene.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't work. I made an edit in my post adding more information. It seems the problem is in the fxml.

Comment: OK, it works in general, but in the specific case of MigLayout, I can't really help as I've never used that.

Comment: Hello again jewlsea. I have to apologize, because with your solution and after the edition I made, it works for the first screen. I only had to add that line after stage.show(). However, the rest of screens are taking the first screen's size. Ideas?